# The background mask cuts off part of the foreground layer

Tags: swift, uikit, calayer, cashapelayer

Recently ran into a problem in one of my tasks. I tried to solve this problem for two days. Finally I came here.

I have a custom progress view. Don't look at the colors, they are so awful just for the debugging process to see better.
[the look I have now] [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gr2uG.png)
[the look I want to have] [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wFgV5.png)

As you can see, there is a red dot at the end of the progress layer, but it is cut at the top and bottom ...
And it shouldn't be like that ...

Also I will leave here all the code I have, maybe someone
can help me.

Thank you all in advance for your time.

```
import UIKit

class PlainProgressBar: UIView {
    //MARK: - Private
    //colour of progress layer : default -> white
    private var color: UIColor = .white {
        didSet { setNeedsDisplay() }
    }

    // progress numerical value
    private var progress: CGFloat = 0.0 {
        didSet { setNeedsDisplay() }
    }
    
    private var height : CGFloat = 0.0 {
        didSet{ setNeedsDisplay() }
    }
    
    
    private let progressLayer = CALayer()
    private let dotLayer = CALayer()
    private let backgroundMask = CAShapeLayer()
    
    private func setupLayers() {
        layer.addSublayer(progressLayer)
        layer.addSublayer(dotLayer)
    }
    
    //MARK:- Public
    // set color for progress layer
    func setColor(progressLayer color: UIColor){
        self.color = color
    }
    
    func set(progress: CGFloat){
        if progress > 1.0{
            self.progress = 1.0
        }
        if progress < 0.0{
            self.progress = 0.0
        }
        if progress >= 0.0 && progress <= 1.0{
            self.progress = progress
        }
    }
    
    func set(height: CGFloat){
        self.height = height
    }
    
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        setupLayers()
    }
    
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: coder)
        setupLayers()
    }
    
    //Main draw function for view
    override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {
        backgroundMask.path = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: CGRect(origin: .zero, size: CGSize(width: rect.width, height: height)), cornerRadius: rect.height * 0.25).cgPath
        layer.mask = backgroundMask
        
        let dotOnProgressLayer = CGRect(origin: .zero, size: CGSize(width: 10.0, height: 10.0))
        let progressRect = CGRect(origin: .zero, size: CGSize(width: rect.width * progress, height: height))
        
        progressLayer.frame = progressRect
        progressLayer.backgroundColor = color.cgColor
        dotLayer.frame = dotOnProgressLayer
        dotLayer.cornerRadius = dotLayer.bounds.width * 0.5
        dotLayer.backgroundColor = #colorLiteral(red: 0.9254902005, green: 0.2352941185, blue: 0.1019607857, alpha: 1).cgColor
        dotLayer.position = CGPoint(x: progressLayer.frame.width ,y: progressLayer.frame.height / 2)
    }

}
```

```
  progressView.set(height: 4.5)
        progressView.setColor(progressLayer: UIColor(ciColor: .green))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are masking the views layer with

```
layer.mask = backgroundMask
```

So anything outside the mask will no be drawn.

Comment: Yeah, I know that, but I can not implement something else, i'he tried to replace it in xib, or add another UIView only for progress lines, but non of that was not working good, and by saying this, I want to explain that personally I don't know the right way to do that.
But, thanks)

Comment: You can apply the mask only to the progressLayer